# How to change mime type of email notifications sent by PeopleSoft?

Tags: email, peoplesoft

I work near some PeopleSoft guys and they asked how to change a link in an email notification sent by PeopleSoft so that it is friendly, basically they just wanted the use of an HTML anchor.

After sitting down with them and looking through the code I found that the default mime type for all email notifications is text/plain and there does not seem to be any kind of an email API that is called which would allow setting the mime type of the body to text/html. Furthermore, there seems to be no general email configuration in PeopleSoft to, for example, set the default mime type for all emails.

Do you know how to change the mime type of an email in PeopleSoft?

Comment: Are you using sendmail in PeopleCode?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Tools 8.49..
Try this out:

```
local PT_MCF_MAIL:MCFOutboundEmail &email;
&email = Create MCFOutboundEmail();

&email.From = "someemail@from.com";
&email.Recipients = "someemail@to.com";
&email.Subject = "Sample HTML Email";

&email.Text ="<html><body><H1><b>Hello World</b></H1></body></html>";

&email.ContentType = "text/html";

Local integer &result = &email.Send();
```